# Using ASP.NET AutoCompleteExtender not working with Bootstrap Modal Popup in Chrome and Safari

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, autocompleteextender

I have an AutoCompleteExtender inside Bootstrap Modal Popup on a asp.net webpage, and it works beautifully in Mozilla FireFox. But in Chrome and safari AutoCompleteExtender Is Not Working

Has anyone else experienced this? Any kind of workaround? I was hoping that its Hiding Behind modal popup in Chrome and Safari, but I can't find any such technique.

I am hoping someone else out there has deal with this. Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="col-lg-10">    <ul style="list-style: none">
     <li>
       <select class="width-80 chosen-select tag-input-style" style="width: 350px;" id="ddlOnlyPortals"
                                                                name="ddlOnlyPortals" runat="server" data-placeholder="Choose Default Portal">
         </select>
      </li>
     </ul>    </div>
```

bind This ddlonlyportal from codebehind file and see the affect..exactly you say..

Answer (score 0):

use following css with z-index higher

```
.CompletionListCssClass 
{
    Z-INDEX: 9999 !important;
}

extender.CompletionListCssClass = "CompletionListCssClass" ;
```